# Is it possible to fill a checkedlistbox with items from an sql database?

Tags: c#, sql

Sorry if this is a stupid question! I'm very new to coding and only have limited access to the internet whilst at work, I was just wondering if this is possible? and If so do you have a useful link for me to read over?

A quick overview of what I'm trying to do.

I have form1 and form2, form1 has a datagridview box that pulls data from the database, when I click on a cell it opens form2, which has a checklistbox which I want to now put code in so it pulls the data from a specific column and checks a box if the cell that was clicked applies to it.

Go easy on me if this question is stupid ^^, thanks in advance!

Some code I have produced so far! Which pulls the boxes from the database, but I also need to check the boxes too..

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("=");
            con.Open();
            string query = "select ID from dbo.report";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow datarow in dt.Rows)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(datarow["ReportID"]);
```

Edited: put current coding in.

Comment: Use a DataTable as the source of the datagridview.  Any column in the DataTable that is defined as a Boolean will appear in the DGV as a checkbox.

Comment: See my response from earlier today : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881435/how-to-build-nested-treeview-in-c-sharp/40882170#40882170

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the feedback! I've saved that for later, but right now I need the checklistbox separate from the DGV

Comment: I'm confused.  The title states "checklistbox with items".  How do you file one box with items (plural)?

Comment: @jdweng A checkedlistbox can contain multiple items no?, again apologies for any confusion, I am new to this

Comment: You are correct.  You have to check the item by the index number : checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(0, true);

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to bind checkboxlist from database.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("=");
        con.Open();
        string query = "select ID,NAME from dbo.report";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(ds);
        checkedListBox1.DataValueField = "ID" 
        checkedListBox1.DataTextField = "NAME"
        checkedListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        checkedListBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: How would you check/uncheck values from a column in the dbo.report table? For example if you had a column "active" with values 0/1, how would you automatically set the ones that have a value of 1 checked?